# How to use cloud config in pxe boot?

Tags: pxe-boot, cloud-init, netboot

I am using netbootxyz in order to boot my Ubuntu environments. In matter of the facts, is that I am using pre-seed configuration. The problem is that there are some minor bugs:

- gnome-terminal is not working.
- can not use post commands at all.

Could you please advise if you have used already the new installer, "cloud-config"? How can I implement it since I really enjoy the netbootxyz container?

Comment: This looks like a good set of details to get started with, but it is a USB based install. https://www.jimangel.io/posts/automate-ubuntu-22-04-lts-bare-metal/ I'm not clear how to arrange the user-data location for the PXE installer to pick it up though.